# How to use window variables between fixtures for TestCafe?

Tags: javascript, automated-tests, e2e-testing, web-testing, testcafe

I have one fixture, "Page1" which I use a random word generator to create a named input box. I will need to use this variable on a different fixture, "Page2". How can I accomplish this? We can't use window for testcafe, and all efforts to export the result in a `ReferenceError: fixture is not defined` error.

On Page 1, I have such code:

```
const words = require('random-words');
export let inputName;

fixture('Page1'); 


test('Create Page1', async (t) => {
    await loginPage.login();

    inputName = `input ${words()}`;
```

and on Page 2

```
import {inputName} from './page1';
```

if I take out the import statement everything works.

Answer (score 4):

You can store your variables in a separate file, e.g.:

*fixture1.js*

```js
import getInputName from './get-input-name';   
 
fixture('Page1');   
 
test('Create Page1', async t => {
    await t.typeText('input', getInputName());
});
```

*fixture2.js*

```js
import getInputName from './get-input-name';
 
fixture('Page2');   
 
test('Create Page2', async t => {
    await t.typeText('input', getInputName());
});
```

*get-input-name.js*

```js
const words = require('random-words');  
 
let inputName = null;   
 
export default function getInputName () {
    if (!inputName)
        inputName = `input ${words()}`;       
 
    return inputName;
}
```

To get more info about using helpers in TestCafe, have a look at [a recipe in Docs](https://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/documentation/recipes/extract-reusable-test-code/create-helpers.html).